# Delay between key pressing in C#

Tags: c#, key

I've got a method, that searches some data in DataGridView on KeyPress event and then focuses a row where input string was found (if is found).

```
private string input;
    private void Find_Matches()
    {            
        if (input.Length == 0) return;

        for (int x = 0; x < dataGridViewCustomers.Rows.Count; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < dataGridViewCustomers.Columns.Count; y++)
                if (dataGridViewCustomers.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value.ToString().Contains(input))
                    dataGridViewCustomers.Rows[x].Selected = true;

     }

private void dataGridViewCustomers_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {            
        input += e.KeyChar.ToString();
        Find_Matches();
    }
```

How to count a delay between keys pressings and, if it is more than 1 second, clear the "input" string? It's necessary for uninterrupted searching.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leveraging `System.Timers.Timer` it's done like this:

```
private Timer myTimer = new Timer(1000); //using System.Timers, 1000 means 1000 msec = 1 sec interval

public YourClassConstructor()
{
    myTimer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
}

private void TimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    input = string.Empty;
    myTimer.Stop();
}

// this is your handler for KeyPress, which will be edited
private void dataGridViewCustomers_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{            
    if (myTimer.Enabled) myTimer.Stop(); // interval needs to be reset
    input += e.KeyChar.ToString();
    Find_Matches();
    myTimer.Start(); //in 1 sec, "input" will be cleared
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use System.Threading.Timer.
Pass a callback to the timer that will clear input.
Every time the KeyPress event raised, you have to update timer's interval to 1000 ms

```
timer.Change(0,1000);
```

or

```
timer.Change(1000,0);
```

I don't remember correct argument sequence for Change method, try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer set to a 1 second interval, and reset the timer in the KeyPress() method.
Also reset the timer in the handler for it. This will cause the timer's handler to be invoked when a second has elapsed since the last keystroke.

Inside the timer's handler, do whatever you need to do when a second has elapsed since the last keystroke.

I recommend using this timer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

You can make it call back on the UI thread (which I think you will want) by setting the SynchronizingObject to your form/control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx

Comment: This would cause as many calls to the "whatever you need to do when a second has elapsed" as keys have been pressed.

Comment: @gustavogbc No it wouldn't because you RESET the timer whenever another key is pressed. So if you press another key before the timer has fired, it will reset and will not fire until a second has passed since the last key was pressed. Note how I say " reset the timer in the KeyPress() method".

Comment: @gustavogbc (By reset, I mean to call Stop() followed by Start())

Answer (score 0):

At first create a new `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and configure it as follows:

```
_TimerFilterChanged.Interval = 800;
_TimerFilterChanged.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.OnTimerFilterChangedTick);
```

Then in your code add the following method:

```
private void OnTimerFilterChangedTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _TimerFilterChanged.Stop();
    Find_Matches();
}
```

Your key press event handler should be changed as follows:

```
private void dataGridViewCustomers_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{            
    input += e.KeyChar.ToString();
    _TimerFilterChanged.Stop();
    _TimerFilterChanged.Start();
}
```